# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named xlrd

Tags: python, aws-lambda, xlrd

I'm trying to run a aws lambda function with python

this is my code:

```
import boto3
import xlrd
import re
from PIL import Image

source_bucket = "general"
destination_bucket = "sarit-sh-filtered-images"
# Get the bucket and object key from the Event
#  bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
 # key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
def remove_nonalfabetic(name):
    clean_name = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", "", name)
    return clean_name

def get_employees_list(excel_file):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    employees_list = book.sheet_by_name('names').col_values(0,1)
    return employees_list

def add_logo(employee_pic,logo):
        mimage = Image.open(employee_pic)
        limage = Image.open(logo)

        # resize logo
        wsize = int(min(mimage.size[0], mimage.size[1]) * 0.25)
        wpercent = (wsize / float(limage.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(limage.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))

        simage = limage.resize((wsize, hsize))
        mbox = mimage.getbbox()
        sbox = simage.getbbox()

        # right bottom corner
        box = (mbox[2] - sbox[2], mbox[3] - sbox[3])
        mimage.paste(simage, box)
        mimage.save(employee_pic)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(source_bucket)
    dest_bucket = s3.Bucket(destination_bucket)
    employees_list = get_employees_list('employees.xlsx')

    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=source_bucket+'/',Delimiter='/',Suffix='.png'):
        dest_key = obj.key
        employees_name = remove_nonalfabetic(obj.name)
        print(dest_key , employees_name)
        if employees_name in employees_list:
            s3.Object(dest_bucket.employees_name, dest_key).copy_from(CopySource = {'Bucket': obj.bucket_name, 'Key': obj.key})
```

when i'm trying to test this function im getting an error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named xlrd

the function is running inline, no files or zip

can you please help me solve this issue ?
thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 1):

xlrd is not a standard library in AWS lambda. you need to create a deployment package with virtualenv

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html